# I am unable to create a live pen drive in my OS

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a pen drive. Although I have tried to create a live usb from UNetbootin on Zorin OS 10 ultimate, it still will not boot. Instead, it just repeatedly counts down from 10.

I have also tried creating a persistence file, that has also failed.

Comment: Have you tried using `dd`?

Answer (score 0):

Use dd command from terminal. Ubuntu startup disk creator didn't work in my machine as well.

*dd if=/dev/sr0 of=/home/hope/exampleCD.iso bs=512*

Replace /dev/sr0 with the address of your pen drive. Use fdisk command. "of" is the path of iso image stored in your machine.